# Windows32 API: "mov edi,edi" on function entry?

Tags: windows, x86, calling-convention, seh

I'm stepping through Structured Error Handling recovery code in Windows 7
(e.g, what happens after SEH handler is done and passes back "CONTINUE" code).
Here's a function which is called:

```
 7783BD9F  mov         edi,edi  
 7783BDA1  push        ebp 
 7783BDA2  mov         ebp,esp   
 7783BDA4  push        1  
 7783BDA6  push        dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]  
 7783BDA9  push        dword ptr [ebp+8]  
 7783BDAC  call        778692DF  
 7783BDB1  pop         ebp  
 7783BDB2  ret         8
```

I'm used to the function prolog of "push ebp/mov ebp,esp".  What's the purpose
of the "mov edi,edi"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raymond Chen (one of the Microsoft developers) has answered this exact question:

- [Why do Windows functions all begin with a pointless MOV EDI, EDI instruction?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/21/10214405.aspx)

And he links an even earlier reference:

- [Why does the compiler generate a MOV EDI, EDI instruction at the beginning of functions?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ishai/archive/2004/06/24/165143.aspx)

Basically, it leaves space for a jump instruction to be inserted during hot patching.

Comment: Well, that's about the fastest answer I ever got!  Thanks, Ben. (So fast, SO, won't even let me accept it yet!)

Comment: @IraBaxter: You're quite welcome.  BTW, I'm quite surprised that you don't religiously read "The Old New Thing", considering the type of products you work on.  But I guess Raymond writes so much that it's easy to forget what you've seen.

Comment: Maybe because I don't know about "The Old New Thing"?   What is it, and why should I care?

Comment: @IraBaxter: My link will take you there.  Raymond writes about some quirk of Windows implementation rationale just about every single day.

Comment: "Hot patch" = " 2 byte nop" preceded by "5 byte space for long relative jmp".   Why didn't they just put in a "5 byte long relative jmp to next instruction"?  Or just overwrite the function prolog? Oh well.

Comment: @Ira: Both those questions are answered, if you read the comments as well as the initial post.

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways to make a long NOP. LEA BX, [BX+0] (67,66,8D,5F,00) would do nothing and use 5 bytes.

Comment: @Alexey: But how do you replace that atomically so that no other thread ever executes a torn instruction?  With the two-byte local jump, you first fill in the long jump outside the existing flow of execution, then patch in the local jump with a single atomic write.  Every other thread either executes the `mov edi,edi` or the new `jmp $-5`, but no tearing is possible.

Comment: The article describes the atomic update with 2/5 byte combination, yes I had read that.  But if they had used just a 5-byte relative jump, an atomic update (trivially done with a single store) of the relative jump target (4 bytes) would have worked just fine.  ... actually, I don't know if that would work. Are 4 byte DWORD stores atomic across cache line boundaries? I'll bet not.  Updating the one byte relative branch offset is only a single byte write and can't cross a cache line, that's probably the real reason.

Comment: @IraBaxter: The reason the code doesn't use a jump instruction as built is also described in the comments -- because it causes a pipeline flush on some processors, so would really hurt performance.  The point about the 2 bytes crossing a cache boundary was brought up, along with the reason it isn't a problem: the linker ALIGN option.

Comment: What makes no sense to me is why they chose `mov edi,edi` instead of an actual 2-byte NOP like `66 90`, or even better lengthening the first instruction by e.g. encoding `push ebp` with the 2-byte opcode + modrm encoding, not the special-case short form with the register number embedded in the opcode byte.  That would cost no extra instructions / uops, and only 1 extra byte total.  And could still work as a "this is hotpatchable" signature because you'd never use that encoding at the start of a function otherwise.