# MOV instruction with same destination and source operand

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I noticed a strange usage of `mov` instruction by gcc in which the source and destination operand were the same.

```
mov     edi, edi
```

Code: https://godbolt.org/z/kANkNL

Note that clang also generates a `mov` instruction, but moves data from edi to eax. (which is also not obvious to me. Why use eax register at all? It is a void function).

What's the purpose of this `mov` instruction?

Comment: That's zero extending edi into rdi. Looking for the duplicate...

Comment: @phuclv Yes, second answer by Jeach explains what Jester pointed in their comment. Thanks.

Comment: See also [Peter's comment on the second duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439289/zero-out-top-32-bits-of-64-bit-register#comment99719418_21439432) which applies to why clang used `eax`.

Comment: on x86 it's a NOP: [Windows32 API: “mov edi,edi” on function entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11337433/995714) but on x86-64 it's a zero extension [Why did GCC generate mov %eax,%eax and what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11910501/995714). Please tag the correct 32/64-bit architecture